# how to edit a XML file in edit mode in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xml

I am trying to update my grid in edit mode using xml but I am not able to do it.

I am able to edit only one element but dont know how to edit more than one

my xml file looks like below

```
<CATALOG>
  <CD>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <Application>Dot Net</Application>
    <status>Available</status>
    <LastUpdate>02-07-2017</LastUpdate>
    <Comments>The Rox for July has been loaded</Comments>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <Application>JFORWBK</Application>
    <status>Available</status>
    <LastUpdate>05-07-2017</LastUpdate>
    <Comments>DeLorean data has been loaded</Comments>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <ID>3</ID>
    <Application>Codepress</Application>
    <status>Open for Input</status>
    <LastUpdate>06-07-2017</LastUpdate>
    <Comments>The Rox for July has been loaded</Comments>
  </CD>
</catalog>
```

When i open the data in grid in edit mode basis of id than I am able to update on single element

How can i update all the element in one time if i have the value in hidden field.

I am able to update my xml element on basis of id.I am only able to update one element in 1 time..

Code as follows:

```
 ID = Request.QueryString["sID"];
                    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
                    string filepathsUpdate = Server.MapPath("Action.xml");
                    xmlDoc.Load(filepathsUpdate);
                    XmlNode node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/CATALOG/CD[ID=" + ID + "]/Action");
                    node.InnerText = ssplit[0];
                    xmlDoc.Save(filepathsUpdate);
```

Now How do it update ,, and comments in edit mode on click of update button in C# on server side.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use a loop to update them one by one like.

Put you all hidden field values in `Ids` list. Then use a loop to update the XML.

```
List<int> Ids = new List<int>();
Ids.Add(1);

for (int i = 0; i < Ids.Count; i++)
{
    ID = Request.QueryString["sID"];
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    string filepathsUpdate = Server.MapPath("Action.xml");
    xmlDoc.Load(filepathsUpdate);
    XmlNode node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/CATALOG/CD[ID=" + Ids[i].ToString() + "]/Action");
    node.InnerText = ssplit[0];
    xmlDoc.Save(filepathsUpdate);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In LINQ to XML it is pretty straightforward:

```
var id = Request.QueryString["sID"];
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("Action.xml");
var catalogDescendants = doc.Descendants("CATALOG");
foreach (var cd in catalogDescendants)
{
    //you can update the id here for whatever you want
    cd.Element("ID").Value = id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the XmlNodeList and iterate for each XmlNode within that list and perform an update.

If memory serves it ought to be along the lines of

```
foreach(XmlNode node in XmlDoc.selectNodes("nodename")){node.innerText = "updated value here";}
```